# Changing bootstrap carousel indicators to bullets

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm trying to align carousel indicators vertically on the left side as bullet points. I took help from @stackoverflow and aligned almost. A little problem I'm facing is that I don't know whether it's an active indicator or non-active indicators which are moving to right slightly every time when slide changes on carousel. I want this not to happen. Please see and tell what I'm missing.

Here's the outline of my code:

HTML:

```
<section className="site-carousel">
<Carousel>
<Carousel.Item>
    <img className="d-block w-100" src={require("../Assets/Images/hair_salon_1.jpg").default}/>
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Hair Salon</h3>
      <p className="d-block w-100">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img className="d-block w-100" src={require("../Assets/Images/hair_salon_2.jpg").default}/>
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Hair Color</h3>
      <p className="d-block w-100">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  <Carousel.Item>
    <img className="d-block w-100" src={require("../Assets/Images/hair_salon_3.jpg").default}/>
    <Carousel.Caption>
      <h3>Hair Stylists</h3>
      <p className="d-block w-100">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </Carousel.Caption>
  </Carousel.Item>
  </Carousel>
</section>
```

CSS

```
ol.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2%;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  right: 95%;
  left: 15%;
  width: 3%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
ol.carousel-indicators li{
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What wrong with the alignment caused by your logic in css. You pushed the dots 95% of slide width to the left and pushed them at the same time 15% of slide width to the right. It does not even add up to 100% of slide width :D

```
ol.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;  
  right: 95%;
  left: 15%;  
}
```

You may consider to edit it to:

```
ol.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;  
  right: 95%; 
}
```